# problem vuejs route does not change the view depending on the component used vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have the signup component but not the login component yet the login route works

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
    <Login />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Login from "../components/login.vue";
export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    Login,
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

here route

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Acceuil from "../views/Acceuil.vue";
import Login from "../views/Login.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Acceuil",
    component: Acceuil,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/login",
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        // route level code-splitting
        // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
        // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
        //component: () =>
        //import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Login.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

here APP.vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

here component login.vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <section
    class="hauteur stopPadMarg container-fluid d-sm-flex justify-content-between"
  >
    <div class="stopPadMarg bg-primary col-sm-2">
      <br />
      <img
        src="../assets/image/icon.png"
        width="80px"
        class="rounded-circle"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <!--  <p class="text-white">S'inscrire</p> -->

      <!-- <p class="stopPadMarg text-white">Se connecter</p> <router-link class="text-white" to="/login">login</router-link>-->
      <router-link class="text-white" to="/login">login</router-link>
      <br />
      <br />
      <router-link class="text-white" to="/">S'inscrire</router-link>
    </div>
    <form class=" bg-primary col-lg-4" action="post">
      <div class="hauteur stopPadMarg form-group">
        <img
          src="../assets/image/icon-left-font-monochrome-white.png"
          width="200"
          alt="logo-titre"
        />
        <br />
        <label class="text-white" for="email">
          Email
        </label>
        <br />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" />
        <br />
        <label class="text-white" for="mdp">Mot de passe </label>
        <br />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mdp" />
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-light text-primary" type="submit">
          Se connecter
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="bg-primary col-sm-2"></div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Login",
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

what to do so that the component is displayed in front I do not know what is happening yet everything looks normal knowing that the signup route is displayed correctly and the login route changes but remains the signup component ??

despite this it loads the signup component and not login

[image front signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Visqk.png)

[route login with component signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYMd0.png)

Comment: do you added <view-router> inside your Accueil.vue file?

Comment: The problem is to solve it is the login name which was repeated several times and which made a conflict.

 I rename my components to connect so as not to have the same names It only duplicated the routes without applying the components I think.